# Which rules should I use for Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When I use this rules for firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

it tells them insecure which I understand as any authenticated user can access them

and when I use this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /Users/{document} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

My app is not able to write to firestore

code:

```
name = edit_name.getText().toString();

HashMap<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("name", name);

db.collection("Users").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid).set(map);
```

variables:

```
String name;
EditText edit_name;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

I wanted it to add a field in Users Collection but i get an error that permission was denied

Comment: If you want to allow access to the `Users` collection, change `match /some_collection/{document} {` to `match /Users/{document} {`.

Comment: in my rules it is Users i changed it after posting the ques but i still get an error permission denied

Comment: We need to be able to see the code that you're running that triggers these rules, along with the document data.  Rules alone don't do anything - they are only meaningful when matched with data and code.  Please edit the question to include enough information that anyone can use to reproduce and observe the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the questions is closed now.

Comment: it is submit for review

Comment: @AlexMamo it has reopened

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated when you try to write the data?

Comment: Yes first i authenticate when it succeeds then i try to write

Comment: A possibility is the data being written (map) does not have a `author_id` field of the value within the field is a mismatch. We don't know what `map` resolves to but that would be helpful. I would also change your rules to this `if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid`. Lastly, if you're not auth'd you can't write so that could be the issue as well.